# Copying values from one vector to another vector

Tags: matlab

I have a vector which is 5000 x 1 & contain doubles, called NewVector. I have another two vectors, one of which is also a 5000 x 1 called OldVector. I then have a vector called CompanyIndex which is a double type as well which contains all the row numbers of OldVector where I would like the data to be copied over to the NewVector. This vector (CompnayIndex) sizes will change every time the code updates.

An example of what I'm looking to do.

```
Old Vector     New Vector     CompanyIndex          Result I'm looking for - New Vector
3              0              2                     0
6              0              3                     6
12             0              5                     12
9              0                                    0
36             0                                    36
```

Comment: `New_Vector(CompanyIndex) = Old_Vector(CompanyIndex)`

Comment: thanks again, works! I assumed doing it like that it would only return 6,12, & 36. However is because CompanyIndex is not a logical vector why this doesn't happen?

Comment: Don't forget to use `NewVector = zeros(size(OldVector))` in case the last index of `CompanyIndex` is less than the length of `OldVector`.

Comment: @mHelpMe It works because `New_Vector` is already defined as a vector of same size as Old_Vector and we index into both using `CompanyIndex`, so values from identical places are copied.